# Help for a new character similar to sqcup with yellow filler

Tags: symbols, color

How can I add the character in the figure in a formula? I would like a yellow filled character, wider then `\sqcup`

[image]

Comment: I would like a character more larger than \sqcup and also I would like that inside it's yellow.

Comment: You may want to mention up front, rather than in a comment, that the yellow filler inside the square cup is essential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it you're interested in a version of the `\bigsqcup` macro that "fills" the cup with yellow color. (The size of the symbol produced by `\bigsqcup` is larger in display-style math mode than it is in text-style math mode.)

The following solution sets up a macro called `\yellowbigsqcup`. It can be used both in display-style math expressions or in text-mode (inline) math material; for the latter appliation, specify the option `\textstyle`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor} % for "\fcolorbox" macro
\newcommand\yellowbigsqcup[1][\displaystyle]{%
  \fboxrule0pt
  \ifx#1\textstyle\fboxsep-0.6pt\else\fboxsep-1.25pt\fi
  \mathrel{\fcolorbox{white}{yellow}{$#1\bigsqcup$}}}

\begin{document}
\[
a \bigsqcup b \quad a \yellowbigsqcup b
\]

\[ \textstyle
a \bigsqcup b \quad a \yellowbigsqcup[\textstyle] b
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can customize the parameters, if you so wish.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pict2e,xcolor}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ysqcup}{\mathbin{\,\mathpalette\ryuk@ysqcup{(0,1)(0,0)(1,0)(1,1)}}\,}
\newcommand{\ysqcap}{\mathbin{\,\mathpalette\ryuk@ysqcup{(0,0)(0,1)(1,1)(1,0)}}\,}
\newcommand{\ryuk@ysqcup}[2]{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{%
    \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\mkern15mu$}%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{\wd\z@}%
    \begin{picture}(1,1)
    \linethickness{0.05\unitlength}
    \put(0,0){\color{yellow}\rule{\unitlength}{\unitlength}}
    \polyline#2
    \end{picture}%
  }}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$x\sqcup a\ysqcup b\ysqcap c_{\ysqcup\ysqcap}$

\end{document}
```

[image]